# How can I get a diagnostic manual or steps for the Mac trackpad?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, trackpad

A1534 early 2016

For some odd reason the trackpad and keyboard both are not working. The computer turns on just fine. I check the schematics and checked all the rails related to trackpad and keyboard, it includes:

PP3V3_G3H_KBD_F (3.31V verified)

PP3V3_S4_TPAD_F (3.33V verified)

PP5V_S4_TPAD_F (5.13V verified)

PP5V_S0_KBD_F (5.13V verified)

I also replaced the trackpad. IPD connectors are fine they are getting continuity, keyboard backlight flex is fine as well.  I’m now all out of ideas, it’s not a logic issue or trackpad issue.

Should I just wing it and replace the keyboard and hope it works?

Comment: @JoyJin you mean the diagnostics? When you boot into CMD+D

Comment: @JoyJin yes I got error code PFM001 (there may be a problem with the system management controller, smc) I look it up and people say it’s water damage I can assure you that’s not the case with this computer.

Comment: It indicates a SMC problem. Try SMC reset? If that doesn't work, you may have a logic board problem: https://zh.ifixit.com/Answers/View/627569/Diagnostic+Error+Codes+PFM001+PPT001+NDC001.

Comment: @JoyJin yeah I did the smc reset. Waited for the 2 chimes and all. No luck.

Comment: @JoyJin any chance it could be a bad keyboard?

Comment: In the article it mentioned liquid spill. Had you spilled liquid onto your machine at some point?

Comment: You can send your mac to Apple Store for diagnosis. It's free, so that's an option.